# How to assign site and register a user programmatically in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have Liferay installed on my local server and I'm making a site where registration is necessary and one more thing as you all have seen that for assigning a site to a particular user admin has a right to do that but I don't want that I want that thing to be done programmatically. Basically I don't want any person to be admin and doing for every user which is going to register so is there any API or some app or some code that I can write it so that my problem can be solved. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want: There's a standard set of roles, usergroups, sites that you can assign to any new user (available through the UI). Also, Liferay has an API for everything that happens through the backend.

The technical name (in the API) for sites is "group". You can use [`UserLocalService.addGroupUser`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalService.html#addGroupUser%28long,%20long%29) to create a direct membership of a user to a site. If a user shouldn't be able to do that themselves, make sure to create a private or restricted site: In an open site, they could make themselves a member easily (by design).

Also, [these](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) [two](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/part-ii-7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) articles by James Falkner might help you making sense of the API, maybe they even have the sample code that you're looking for.